# how can i write to text file out of scope it is defined in?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

How can i write to a text file outside of the scope it is created in?

say for example my code looks a bit like this:

```
try
{
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);
}
catch (NullReferenceException) //unable to create file
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot create file");
    //end program
}

file.WriteLine("hello world!") //error at compile time here 
//                  "The name 'file' does not exist in current context"
```

if the file cannot be created the program is ended straight away
can i do this or not?

Comment: So you can't create the file, but you want to write to the file... Don't you see the logical problem here? You should probably `return;` after the `MessageBox.Show`, and put a `StreamWriter file;` BEFORE the `try {`

Comment: shouldve been more specific if the file cannot be created the program is ended straight away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly it is very complex to use the `using` pattern in this case. This is a "bad" thing...

```
StreamWriter file = null;

try
{
    try
    {
        file = new StreamWriter(path);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //unable to create file
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot create file");
        return;
    }

    file.WriteLine("hello world!");
}
finally
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        file.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Note that I don't like this code for TWO reasons:

- You can't easily use the `using` pattern. I consider the `using` pattern to be VERY important
- You are supposing that if you can create the file then everything will go correctly... This is WRONG. EVERY time you write to the file something could go kaboom (throw an `Exception`)... The disk could be full for example... Even simply closing a file you have written to could go kaboom (for example `StreamWriter` is buffered, so it doesn't write immediately. When you close it the buffer is written, but NOW the disk is full :-) )

Comment: i usually use `using` for files but in this case the file is used as a logfile so its quite tricky to use `using`

Comment: also is there a difference between `dispose` and `close`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint There is a guarantee that a `Dispose()` will `Close()` the file :-) Internally in `StreamWriter` both the `Dispose()` and the `Close()` call the `protected Dispose(bool disposing)`. From a conceptual standpoint, `Dispose()` should be a terminal condition. There is no return for a Disposed object... But a class could implement both a `Open()` and a `Close()`, so that you can open->close->open->close->open->dispose->end! (or even open->close->dispose->end!)

Answer (score 1):

[this is](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottwil/2005/03/21/trycatch-and-scoping/) may be helpful you..

```
StreamWriter file; 
try
{
    file = new StreamWriter(path);
}
catch (NullReferenceException) //unable to create file
{
   MessageBox.Show("Cannot create file");
   return;
   //end program
}

file.WriteLine("hello world!") //error at compile time here 
//"The name 'file' does not exist in current context"
```